# Is it possible to reassign the whole state in a slice reducer (using Redux ToolKit)?

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit's `createSlice()`.
And trying to create a reducer that populates data from an external source into the redux state.
I'm trying to update the whole state by passing in an object in the action payload:

```
.
    reducers: {
        populateData: (state, action) => {
            state = action.payload
        }
.
```

but it will only work if I create a reducer for each object key.
Is there a way to do this all at once?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to update the **entire** state and not just the slice? I don't think you can do that with a slice reducer as that has only control over the slice allocated to it. You could do it with a root reducer though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding, and I actually just wrote a new ["Writing Reducers with Immer" docs page](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers) yesterday that answers this question.  Quoting that:

> A common mistake is to try assigning `state = someValue directly`. This will not work! This only points the local state variable to a different reference. That is neither mutating the existing state object/array in memory, nor returning an entirely new value, so Immer does not make any actual changes.

Instead, you want: `return action.payload`, which will replace the existing state entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this problem

***This does not work***

```js
   reducers: {
      setSession: (state, action: PayloadAction<SessionState>) =>
         state = action.payload, 
   },
```

***This does work***

```js
   reducers: {
      setSession: (state, action: PayloadAction<SessionState>) =>
         action.payload, 
   },
```